# Why connects geom_line not to next point when using in gganimate?

Tags: gganimate

When I have this data frame

```
library(ggplot)  
library(gganimate)

data <- tribble(
~year, ~num,
1950, 56,
1951, 59,
1952, 64,
1953, 76,
1954, 69,
1955, 74,
1956, 78,
1957, 98,
1958, 85,
1959, 88,
1960, 91,
1961, 87,
1962, 99,
1963, 104
)
```

and want to make an animated line plot with *gganimate*:

```
ggplot(data, aes(year, num))+geom_point()+geom_line()+transition_reveal(year, num)
```

I get a diagram, in which points and lines are drawn in the wrong sequence.

[image]

What is the reason for this and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
transition_reveal()
```

the first argument (id) regards the group aesthetic (which you don't have). I found that just using id = 1 for a single time series works.

The second argument (along) should be your x aesthetic (in your case the year).

Try:

```
ggplot(data, aes(year, num))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  transition_reveal(1, year)
```